# Find an integral kernel for a partial differential equation: Initial value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, initial-value-problems, integral-transforms

Consider the following partial differential equation with an initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t)=g_{1}(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+g_{2}(x)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+g_{3}(x)\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}
\end{equation}

where $g_{2}(x)=\frac{dg_{1}(x)}{dx}$, $g_{3}(x)=\frac{d^2g_{1}(x)}{dx^2}$. Given that $f(x)$ and $g_{1}(x)$ are known functions, it is possible to numerically solve this IVP using the Euler method (assuming zero spatial derivatives at the boundaries). I, however, was wondering whether it would be possible to *analytically* find a kernel $k(x,\tau)$ such that the solution of this IVP at, e.g., $t=1$ be the following integral transform:

\begin{equation}
u(x,1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(x,\tau)f(\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}

Thank you for your help. Guiding towards a reference would be highly appreciated as well.

Comment: Moving the question to stackoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/430291/478084
Not sure whether I should delete this one or not (?)